# Third party tools to scan ESX hosts, and retrieve the info, from inside my custom application

Tags: networking, network-monitor, virtual-machine, scanning

Currently we are trying to have the ability to scan our ESX hosts, so I want to run a tool which allows scanning ESX hosts inside a network.

For example: a user enters the IP address, username and password and he gets a list of ESX hosts and their info such as IP, MAC, operating system, and any other info.

Can anyone advice if there are free tools that can assist me in achieving this, so I can integrate them with a custom asp.net mvc web application?

Comment: For windows, powershell or wmi scripting might work depending on what **any other info is**.  Windows File sharing and samba will give you access to the file system, if permissions are setup correctly.